# progressDialoge not Updating

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

i have been using AsyncTask to download a certain file and went through a few tutorials and just failed to get the progress bar to move with the download. the code is and AsyncTask that calls a method to do the HTTP connection and then comes back to assort the data in a proper way to manipulate it for the app

this is my AsynTask that is on the MainActivity

```
    private class getFood extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Cursor> {
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

    @Override
    protected Cursor doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Create URL object
        String site = "https://afternoon-ridge-50060.herokuapp.com/allsnacks";
        URL url = createUrl(site);

        // Perform HTTP request to the URL and receive a JSON response back
        String jsonResponse = null;
        try {
            String jsonResponseEmpty = "";

            // If the URL is null, then return early.
            if (url == null) {
                jsonResponse = jsonResponseEmpty;
            }

            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            try {
                assert url != null;
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setReadTimeout(20000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(25000 /* milliseconds */);
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "\"token\": " + token);
                urlConnection.connect();

                // If the request was successful (response code 200),
                // then read the input stream and parse the response.
                if (urlConnection.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                    int fileLength = urlConnection.getContentLength();
                    Log.d("size", String.valueOf(fileLength));
                    inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
                    if (inputStream != null) {
                        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
                        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
                        String line = reader.readLine();

                    jsonResponse = output.toString();
                } else {
                    Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error response code: " + urlConnection.getResponseCode());
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem retrieving the Food JSON results.", e);
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    // Closing the input stream could throw an IOException, which is why
                    // the makeHttpRequest(URL url) method signature specifies than an IOException
                    // could be thrown.
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem making the HTTP request.", e);
        }

        // Extract relevant fields from the JSON response and create a list of {@link Earthquake}s
        //*List<FoodList> Food = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);
        Cursor foodTable = extractFeatureFromJson(jsonResponse);
        // Return the list of {@link Earthquake}s
        Log.d("food", "done");
        return foodTable;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
        // if we get here, length is known, now set indeterminate to false
        mProgressDialog.setProgress(values[0]);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();
        // Create progress dialog
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(loginActivity.this);
        // Set your progress dialog Title
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Downloading");
        // Set your progress dialog Message
        mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading Important Files, Please Wait!");
        mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        mProgressDialog.setMax(100);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        // Show progress dialog
        mProgressDialog.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Cursor data) {

        try {
            int foodNumberColIndex = data.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NDB_NO);
            int foodNameColIndex = data.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_NAME);
            int waterColIndex = data.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_WATER_G);
            int energyColIndex = data.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ENERGY_KCAL);
            int proteinColIndex = data.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_PROTEIN_G);
            int lipidColIndex = data.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_LIPID_TOT_G);
            int ashColIndex = data.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ASH_G);
            int carboColIndex = data.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_CARBOHYDRT_G);

            while (data.moveToNext()) {
                Log.d("in", " progress");

                FoodList foodItem = new FoodList(data.getInt(foodNumberColIndex),
                        data.getString(foodNameColIndex).trim().replace(",", "."),
                        data.getDouble(waterColIndex),
                        data.getDouble(energyColIndex),
                        data.getDouble(proteinColIndex),
                        data.getDouble(lipidColIndex),
                        data.getDouble(ashColIndex),
                        data.getDouble(carboColIndex));

                allFood.add(foodItem);
            }
        } finally {
            data.close();
        }
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        startActivity(intentNew);
    }

    private URL createUrl(String stringUrl) {
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(stringUrl);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Problem building the URL ", e);
        }
        return url;
    }

    private Cursor extractFeatureFromJson(String foodJSON) {
        // If the JSON string is empty or null, then return early.
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(foodJSON)) {
            return null;
        }
        try {

            // Create a JSONArray from the JSON response string
            JSONArray foodArray = new JSONArray(foodJSON);

            for (int i = 0; i < foodArray.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject foodObject = foodArray.getJSONObject(i);

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                values.put(COLUMN_NDB_NO, foodObject.optInt(COLUMN_NDB_NO));
                values.put(COLUMN_NAME, foodObject.optString(COLUMN_NAME));
                values.put(COLUMN_WATER_G, foodObject.optDouble(COLUMN_WATER_G));
                values.put(COLUMN_ENERGY_KCAL, foodObject.optDouble(COLUMN_ENERGY_KCAL));
                values.put(COLUMN_PROTEIN_G, foodObject.optDouble(COLUMN_PROTEIN_G));
                values.put(COLUMN_LIPID_TOT_G, foodObject.optDouble(COLUMN_LIPID_TOT_G));
                values.put(COLUMN_ASH_G, foodObject.optDouble(COLUMN_ASH_G));
                values.put(COLUMN_CARBOHYDRT_G, foodObject.optDouble(COLUMN_CARBOHYDRT_G));

                foodNutriProvider insert = new foodNutriProvider();

                insert.insert(CONTENT_URI, values);

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // If an error is thrown when executing any of the above statements in the "try" block,
            // catch the exception here, so the app doesn't crash. Print a log message
            // with the message from the exception.
            Log.e("foodSearch", "Problem parsing the earthquake JSON results", e);
            Log.e("foodSearch", foodJSON);
        }

        foodNutriProvider getTable = new foodNutriProvider();

        // Return the list of earthquakes
        return getTable.query(CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: please comment or remove `super.onProgressUpdate(values);` and than check

Comment: @SanjuRajpal didnt fix it

Answer (score 0):

You have to publish the progress and then only the `Integer... values` has proper values.

Something like:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(Context... params) {
    //Part-1 of the task done
    publishProgress(20);

    //Part-2 of the task done
    publishProgress(50);

    //Part-3 of the task done
    publishProgress(100);

    return “success”;
}
```

Comment: and how will these integers represent the actual data that is downloaded

Answer (score 0):

As per android documentation:

"onProgressUpdate(Progress...), invoked on the UI thread after a call to publishProgress(Progress...). The timing of the execution is undefined. This method is used to display any form of progress in the user interface while the background computation is still executing. For instance, it can be used to animate a progress bar or show logs in a text field"

use it